# Building a LazyList with Futures in a non-blocking and lazy way

Tags: scala, nonblocking

I'm building a Scala facade to a Clojure Channel delivering chunks of data and I want to represent it as a `LazyList[Future[Either[String, Int]]]` where the left side can hold an error message and the right side data. Retrieving each chunk from the Channel is a blocking operation and I therefore want to encapsulate each chunk in a Future.

Each chunk result type determines how we should proceed building the lazy list:

1. null: no more results on channel, return list
2. String: add `Left(error)` and return list
3. Int: add `Right(data)` and recurse for next chunk

My questions is wether we can build such list in a lazy and non-blocking way?

This is what I have come up with so far, but the head is evaluated (not lazy) and the Await.result blocks:

```scala
// Clojure "Channel" dummy
case class Channel(vs: Any*) {
  private val it = vs.toIterable.iterator

  // equivalent to the `<!!` Clojure function
  def chunk: Future[Any] = Future {
    // This imitates an expensive blocking operation
    if (it.hasNext) {
      val value = it.next
      println("Retrieving value: " + value)
      value
    } else {
      null
    }
  }
}

def lazyList(channel: Channel): LazyList[Future[Either[String, Int]]] = {
  val ll = channel.chunk.map {
    case null          => LazyList.empty[Future[Either[String, Int]]] // No more values
    case error: String => Future(Left(error)) #:: LazyList.empty[Future[Either[String, Int]]]
    case data: Int     => Future(Right(data)) #:: lazyList(channel)
  }
  Await.result(ll, Duration.Inf)
}

val ll = lazyList(Channel(0, 1, "error"))
// Retrieving value: 0
ll(0)
// (no output since value 0 has already been calculated and memoized)
ll(1)
// Retrieving value: 1
ll(2)
// Retrieving value: error
```

What I'd like to see instead is:

```scala
val ll2 = lazyList2(Channel(0, 1, "error"))
// (no computation)
ll2(0)
// Retrieving value: 0
ll2(1)
// Retrieving value: 1
ll2(2)
// Retrieving value: error
```

Comment: have you considered fs2 as a streaming solution over building your own? It's really well-engineered to solve the problem of having a stream of data produced by some Future-like things efficiently and correctly.

Comment: You can't have a `LazyList[A]` that has values produced by Future and doesn't block. When you want to produce the next A and there is a Future producing A, you must block to wait for it. Your blocking implementation will work as you'd like to see in scala 2.13.4, which fixes eager evaluation of `#::`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're using fs2, you could build a stream from the channel. Given a function

```
def nextChunk: Future[A] = ???
```

you can build a stream with

```
val myStream: Stream[IO, A] = Stream.eval(IO.fromFuture(IO(nextChunk))).repeat
```

in your specific example, your `A` is `Any` which you know is `Int`, `String` or `null` at runtime. You could first lift it into an `Option[Either[String, Int]]` with

```
def typedChunk(channel: Channel): IO[Option[Either[String, Int]]] = 
  IO.fromFuture(IO(channel.nextChunk)).map {
    case null      => None
    case s: String => Some(Left(s))
    case i: Int    => Some(Right(i))
  }
```

then you can build the stream, terminating at `None` with

```
def myTerminatedStream(channel: Channel): Stream[IO, Either[String, Int]] = 
  Stream.eval(typedChunk(channel)).repeat.unNoneTerminate
```

This does all the hard work of keeping referential transparency and making sure it has the correct evaluation semantics for you.

Your requested semantics with LazyList will be tricky: you will only know that your chunk is empty after the Future finished evaluating, so you need to evaluate the Future to know whether your list is empty or not. LazyList is able to do that, but only from blocking operations, not from Future.

Comment: Thanks, @Martijn. All lazily constructed, great. Need to explore fs2 more to see how I will use it for my facade. I'll get back when I have an example up and running for future reference.